# How to decrease the "resolution" or amounts of vertices in a 3D scan?

Tags: vertices

I tried a few days ago to 3D scan an object and also my own face.

The scan includes crazy amounts of vertices and My computer probably isn't the best.

How to decrease the "resolution" or amounts of vertices in a 3D scan? As I said, I'm fairly new to this, so a "for Dummies"-guide would be awesome! Hopefully there are some add-ons or something that will make this process easy
Hope some of you can help!

Sincerely
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

Try decimate modifier. Also face\tris to quads in edit mode, before decimating.
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html

Answer (score 0):

Other than the decimate modifier, you might also want to try retopologizing your mesh (which means rebuilding it out of quads, greatly reducing the number of polygons and also making it easier to reuse your mesh for other works like rigging, UV unwrapping, etc).

There are multiple different tutorials on YouTube on the subject, but if you're short on time and cash, maybe you should try RetopoFlow, which is a FOSS tool to help you with this tedious task. You can find [a quick videotutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hu4NavAy5f4).